# How to use Oracle's UTL_SMTP to send a message body that included an embedded image

Tags: image, oracle, email, html-email

I'm attempting to use Oracle's 11.g's UTL_SMTP to send a message body that includes an embedded image.  I have this process working for a standard text body, and for an eMail that may contain attachments (Word doc, JPG image, etc.).  I'm stuck on making this work with an image embedded in the body of the eMail.  When I include and embedded image, the eMail displays in Outlook 2013 as a red X where the image should be.  The rest of the text appears fine.  The html body of the eMail is passed in to the procedure via "p_html".

My Procedure looks like this:

```
create or replace procedure html_email_attachments(
    p_to               in varchar2,
    p_from             in varchar2,
    p_subject          in varchar2,
    p_text             in varchar2 default null,
    p_html             in varchar2 default null,
    p_smtp_hostname    in varchar2,
    p_smtp_portnum     in varchar2,
    p_smtp_username    in varchar2,
    p_smtp_password    in varchar2,
    p_event_pkey       in number
                                        )
is
    l_boundary         varchar2(255) default 'a1b2c3d4e3f2g1';
    l_connection       utl_smtp.connection;
    l_body_html        clob := empty_clob; --This LOB will be the email message
    l_offset           number;
    l_ammount          number;
    l_temp             varchar2(32767) default null;
    l_encoded_username varchar2(2048);
    l_encoded_password varchar2(2048);
    l_attach_mime      varchar2(1024);
    l_attach_name      varchar2(1024);
    l_attach_blob      blob;
    l_attachment_pkeys DBMS_SQL.varchar2_table;
    l_step             PLS_INTEGER  := 12000; -- A multiple of 3 and <= 24573
    crlf               varchar2(2) := CHR(13) || CHR(10);
    diag               varchar2(4000);
    v_raw              raw(57);
    v_length           integer := 0;
    v_buffer_size      integer := 57;
    v_offset           integer := 1;
begin
--  Store all the attachment primary keys into l_attachment_pkeys   
    Select ma.prim_key  Bulk Collect Into l_attachment_pkeys
    From  mail_attachment ma
    Where ma.event_fkey = p_event_pkey;
--  Encode p_smtp_username and p_smtp_password
    l_encoded_username := UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2
        (UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(p_smtp_username))); 
    l_encoded_password := UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2
        (UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(p_smtp_password))); 
--  set the l_connection variable
    l_connection := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_hostname, p_smtp_portnum); 
--  begin the connection
    utl_smtp.ehlo(l_connection, p_smtp_hostname);--DO NOT USE HELO 
--  authenticate to the server using the encoded username and password
    utl_smtp.command(l_connection, 'AUTH', 'LOGIN'); 
    utl_smtp.command(l_connection, l_encoded_username); 
    utl_smtp.command(l_connection, l_encoded_password);
--  First, establish the mail's From and To.  This is essential
    utl_smtp.mail( l_connection, p_from );
    utl_smtp.rcpt( l_connection, p_to );
--  Define the Header 
    l_temp := l_temp || 'MIME-Version: 1.0'        || crlf;
    l_temp := l_temp || 'To: '       || p_to       || crlf;
    l_temp := l_temp || 'From: '     || p_from     || crlf;
    l_temp := l_temp || 'Subject: '  || p_subject  || crlf;
    l_temp := l_temp || 'Reply-To: ' || p_from     || crlf;
    l_temp := l_temp || 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=' ||
                         chr(34) || l_boundary ||  chr(34) || crlf;

    ----------------------------------------------------
    -- Write the headers
    dbms_lob.createtemporary( l_body_html, false, 10 );
    dbms_lob.write(l_body_html,length(l_temp),1,l_temp);

    ----------------------------------------------------
    -- Write the HTML boundary
    -- Identify the content type as text/html
    -- Determine the offset (initially it's 1)
    -- Write out 
    l_temp   := crlf || crlf ||'--' || l_boundary || crlf;
    l_temp   := l_temp || 'content-type: text/html;' || crlf || crlf;
    l_offset := dbms_lob.getlength(l_body_html) + 1;
    dbms_lob.write(l_body_html,length(l_temp),l_offset,l_temp);

    ----------------------------------------------------
    -- Write the HTML portion of the message
    l_offset := dbms_lob.getlength(l_body_html) + 1;
    dbms_lob.write(l_body_html,length(p_html),l_offset,p_html);
    ----------------------------------------------------
    -- Send the email body in 1900 byte chunks to UTL_SMTP
    l_offset  := 1;
    l_ammount := 1900;
    utl_smtp.open_data(l_connection);

    while l_offset < dbms_lob.getlength(l_body_html) loop
        utl_smtp.write_data(l_connection,
                            dbms_lob.substr(l_body_html,l_ammount,l_offset));
        l_offset  := l_offset + l_ammount ;
        l_ammount := least(1900,dbms_lob.getlength(l_body_html) - l_ammount);
    end loop;
    --The following crlf is necessary after the body is written
    utl_smtp.write_data(l_connection, crlf);
    ----------------------------------------------------
    -- Write the attachments of the message
    -- Loop through all the selected primary keys in l_attachment_pkeys
    While l_attachment_pkeys is null
    Loop
    For i IN l_attachment_pkeys.FIRST .. l_attachment_pkeys.LAST
      Loop
        -- Determine the attachment variables for each instance of attachments
        Select mime_type  into l_attach_mime 
                from mail_attachment where prim_key = l_attachment_pkeys(i);
        Select file_name  into l_attach_name 
                from mail_attachment where prim_key = l_attachment_pkeys(i);
        Select attachment into l_attach_blob 
                from mail_attachment where prim_key = l_attachment_pkeys(i);
        v_length := dbms_lob.getlength(l_attach_blob);

        -- Write out the boundary
        UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_connection, '--' || l_boundary || crlf);
        -- Write out the attachment metadata
        UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_connection, 'Content-Type: ' || l_attach_mime || 
                    '; name=' || chr(34) || l_attach_name || chr(34) || crlf);
        UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_connection, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || 
                    crlf);
        UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_connection, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; 
                    filename="' || l_attach_name || '"' || crlf || crlf);
        --Write out the attachment blob in portions of l_step length
        FOR k IN 0 .. TRUNC((DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_attach_blob) - 1 )/l_step) 
          LOOP
            UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_connection, UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2
              (UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(DBMS_LOB.substr(l_attach_blob, 
                  l_step, k * l_step + 1))));
          END LOOP;
          UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_connection, crlf);
      End Loop;
    End Loop;

    ----------------------------------------------------
    -- Write the final html boundary
    utl_smtp.write_data(l_connection, 
                        crlf || '--' || l_boundary || '--' || crlf);
    ----------------------------------------------------
    -- Close the connection and end
    utl_smtp.close_data(l_connection); 
    utl_smtp.quit( l_connection );
    dbms_lob.freetemporary(l_body_html);
end;
```

A sample "p_html" field looks like this:

```
<p>
    Text right before the image.</p>
<p>
    <img alt="HarryPotter" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAoHBwkHBgoJCAkLCwoMDxkQDw4ODx4WFxIZJCAmJSMgIyIoLTkwKCo2KyIjMkQyNjs9QEBAJjBGS0U+Sjk/QD3/2wBDAQsLCw8NDx0QEB09KSMpPT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT3/wAARCACxARkDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwB9scOF3N781pQoFQHt6n/PWuJ/tCaxkjjjYk8ck5zzW5ZeII2IhvS0c+/G3HSuVprY+i5ovc2HXzOhAOe9AYQPs6lh1XmlRTuO0ZBJOSakZBtYeWNzEEMM5HtTizmrU9CMMCMZwPcUM8YVVXAx945zmnNukJRVy3rio7keVGBclIwvygswX/8AXW8Ty6sCHeglJHUHrmnOUkHysPWq08lvA6iSaFd/QGQZ+tLFcW0mNlzDuyRt3AE1qcrihjwHPSo2tQ3UVfVS6bldGX1Vwf5UGI7wAynPpTJcTIlsRg8Gs+4s8A4BxXVCEY5HNRSWivztppkWOMeyY9FP5VF9kIPQ11cunsCSOnpVM2R3H5aq4XRhC0LdQaT7IR0BrpYdNLjIWrUegmQ/dxRcNznLLT/MmAYECugh0kR42jNbNj4bIwcc5rWj0ZkHzVLkUkc5FZeXhsHNWRuVetal1ZmMEKMsKzJIZzgqnfrU3uFrFCVyXPrT4ppF6k4qwLE7izd6JbXAGxM+tJk3HQzhiNrDmla9cYVkYvnoPSqGoTLbQZRgFXqx4xWN/wAJa9vJmP8AeMDjIXgfnQJXZ23kl0yQRn1qtcIYOPU4BFcbeeOL5VRowokbksy5TbnHOO/FVh4vnu08y5XKg4XB4FKxXKzuhkxjd3qFkJbgViaX4otmlWC+kKb/APVueR9DXVxoigMMEHoaZLViBLffgMOMUtxH5cG2NRjuas7h2oIBUg96LgZEcRIUsKtpagndg+tWVgwMKw/KpNm1MZJ9TVXCxQkXEme1MbrnFWZYyTwOKi8onvx6U7k2IqM08IQ3QfjTsf7MdIR5a3mM3mg4ZTx61UluJZZy8kjZY5Ld69BXTrSNyRAqn1AqvN4cs7gFkRl4wMEYzXFGvFvY+wq4CpbSRydprl9aSbobiRlQ5Cljhq6ODxzK8Krc28CEEZILbmBPbtxWXqmhQWeY45WaUjlMdPyrCuIblTsaEhTnAA6e1bJRnqjgmqtLRnfS+KFkkEWmpu3n/WEfMeP4QfSsm6ma5uI5rh3uHx8xduvPYdBXJx3NzZSFoy8b7So45APXrVq01S4h44kA655AH1rVQszjnNS33N5Yw+RtAUdBjkfjT12JkSRCQYIGSevrVe1vkuFGBtdhkAnrVnaXb3PNWc8o9URxZjKGJijqeCvFa1vr15FkvFBOV43MMfyrNEfPGPzqQRHGO3pVWuYvQ018SXTyBRZ2oB75atSw1K31CNd8qQ3GSDETyfpXMouMYz68VI8EbqpGdwOcjjFHKib6HXmEY+6zduRxUb6ez8hWPtiubM10/wDrLudh6GQ4p4kuT/y3kIHq5pcrI5kdLBbeU20qfpWxaW0Z5PGK5PS9UNpcATs7wnqM5I+ldbZSxTgPGyvEejKe9ZzTRcWnsbVvFGFG0danaINwBzUVogC1eQAdqybNkjKuNMdyWC5+lOm05BZKuzkVrZ5pkiblxRdj5TnJdLURZ6HNZslrt3c4HrXUyQk8dq5L4hXf9k+E7mZAFllIhVh2z1/QU0zNxPOvFviNJbow2+CinG71Pr9a5GW7eXow98DoKUT+e7hfmPXJ78etXhozSfZm3FYpv4Rw3+c8CtLpLUqMLmck/mH5mxGmSACcYNSxmaKeRoiMr2butdZqHhSGz1a0sMKGltzO/cKOwPocg1VXTFu7AXCJsf1x94Zxn6+1HOivZsxUuophtcBHHYdM/wBK7rwb4g8+FdPu2/eRnbGxP3gOgrza+CxuVUc/xYqS2uJ4GHlyEHAIIPcUbmclY912ZPHT2pxjPpXH6Rr+ofY4JSxkTH3W6V01lrltefK4MMv91jwaTTRnctBT2p23irKRBumKGjxQmOxU8vtiozH82BVvaM4NDBAOBVXFYoNFg9KTZ7D8qtMoNN8ulcVixqvhpo1L243gDnHauTv7mazASGMCQHlj1X6e9dvbeJrK+JCyeW/oT1pdR0y21BdxwGxwQOa8de7qj6yjialJ8mIizyqcGOZyW3sx3Fl5zmkExDE4XI74rsW8OKt1vMSSoAQAehrHuvDc8cjFUYj6VarX3PSpujOWkjIFnaXcLeaFDL371QfSLf5/KZ03KQQecmtp9JnjByjD6iq8lo8fXOa2p1X3M8Vg4TV4pHPSaRcRudhVh14p9tqMlv8Au5YzszyWGDn/AAreCgcMSFA+ppk0STxlSq/Uiu6FTmPncRhnAht7y3n+SMgOe1W1QnJz0NVotOiifzNo3D8BVxORW9zzKiEVWydo6fpTgDnnr9KXbipAM88D2FM55MVBv4HBpSpXvQEHUcH1qQc07GfMMQDPIzWvp19cWq4hcBSclcAg1nirELmMjB4qWioyO00nWPtUgW4CxsehHArfVsDrmuCtrpR1A+ldBpupFWSORiUPTJ+7XPOJ0wnc6ANk0tV/Nw3PFPEmTWZqmSFc15f8cWmi0DTlTIjad9/p0GK9QVt1cd8VdFk1rwVcCHmS1IuFAGSwHUf1/Cmhs8K0jTpr957a3hknmaJSsSDOWzjn0r0Ww8GeIRDFLcadDFHZ4cQyzgvdPjrnoqg9BWXoI/s/4awXNk4tprmWRru5SPdKURsKgP1I/OubVtZkuZ71Z7pjbsPNWaY7+eRx06Dp2od5XsWtLHZS6fe2897qmsNbWl3PCVh8y4BS1j6ZwOWbk1SPifQ4NPt7Kxkkn8hNqlYsZbaQDjsOp9aqeMdH1Ge10nUi8jRXcIA3HkZ55HbPuaytI0Q/vkW4PmEKItpzvJ6gqOR65zSirrU0m7aR2INZ0fmSe1fzEZBIpjBYZ6lSezAc1z0M5Vx6HivXPDcV8LDZIsSQSMd77cmQdM88Akd8VxyeCll8S31urP8AZbWQqsYPzynrtB7DHU9qqMyJU2z0X4Xm11PwqY5oo5GgkKfMvNbt/wCErK4JeENE59DxXOfCANHJrVvGm23jlUKpOdrY5GfavRXXNHNqYOPRnFJaa1o8qpEVvEbsQRtH1rZTzHRTKnluRyM5xWpIOpxVKUFuQOKfNcnlsUTnefakz82Km4Vn+XJI4J7Ugi3fdB+gqrisQ4wc0Z9qmCYODTtgouFjzGW8S2IXezyE8EHpXQ6N4nntkUSP5scnBVjkrXJbBtEjZ8zJ6UpmWIrucZz0PU15rou1j7ydelXup7Hq+nahBdY5Gc4ya6OO3jdAdoP4V49pepmC4UhuAegNep6Fq0V5bqN43Y6VkoJSSZ42YYZ01z09UaUllBMmGiUj6Vgax4UhnQyW6gP6V1AIprkY611zw8LXR5dHE1aUrxZ4zqmnSWcpV1I571RA2tiu/wDHkVuIkkLqJO6g84rgCRn5eQaVCTTse5VaxGHVW1mPTnBqRaaV2diO/XtT15r1Iao+WxDsxcZNSAdqVRgHB5NKFOKs4XMCBs4zmnotKq05ugwcfSgnmF2/5xUqrzTEqTOOn51LGmSxtgjnFRz+IHs5RFGq7jIRkjOFA5NB9axNTluI9YkxbLLGyggl8DaRyPzFTYuMrHoOja7JeQeXOBv3BVcdenGa6COXPU15j4cuLljc+fCIkDKUwxIHXgH24rr9N1WQ3CxXD7o34DnGQf8ACsZw10OiM+506txxSnBBDDIIwQarxylTg1YWTNYm6ZxVnodtpmp3saRZiEvmC338ENgkqDwrZH49Kp6j4dtZpna3glZnBVROQFQngk884B4H58Cuk8T2zrF9piGw4AYgdOeM1mStHLahLkgxSLtdSeCD1B9qyk2mddKziTeINQ0KPTLeG71SzjTYFUiXjP8ACQR0I9qy7DTIVh85LlHWQDJjULuHuR6+oxXCX9x4TsdWkSK/lkhj+QQwQF0z7E9QK6PSvFGn6jEsFmzMFXaDjaAPcdqtrQaaWhr3+r7Y2gMaAKNqAYHT2HQVjXrWcto17qMcgW2LXRaMEZbH3d3TnAGD68VBcXCxXzDCuF6kdq53xoXGjW7xzym3numRk3EDAUY46epoirsJSsrnq3w10/7H4OguCnlyX7tdOM5PzHj9K6sr7VleG3VPD2nxq2QtumPptFapkNaPc42QTLxWdMvBNaUuTVOZARQhGc2T34pASmCpPB7HFLjMzIf7u4U7y8CquTYYOTz1p2KAhwWyODjFHNMLHkTapHM7iRRGQeMDt6Vmv+/cySHGOAO9WLixO0sm1WJ6AcVEImTggH3FVGEbaHVLFze5bs544kDE425JJrd0/XJLcpJE5XOMc1y7/My4HA/nUU8jmQuzdMYwaynhlM7KWayhHlkro9VtvHtwkYDbSae/jy5cHbsBryq31R1kVHb5B14rViv7WRgqygN6GsvqbfU1+vYN68iuauuXsus3AkeZ1kHRgePyrH+2XFi4+3QGSI8CaLn8xV4Y68ketSL+GK0hhVHYmpmzlHkW3YLeSO4i823lSSPGSVPT6jtU6cckgDOM1lS6Uol+0WUrWk4Ocx/d/EVYj1RLWHbq8TJITj7RCu5T9V/qPyrqi3Hc8Svar70H8jYChdvOT3p3f2qvFKskQlhkiuIj/HGcgfX0ra0jQbzVAJFVobXvPIvB/wB0d61ukrnEqcpO1iiFyOuKNoPFdFf6Ba2i7k1a3QDqZYS+4+mVI/QVhTzQQXk1pOypdou8LGcxyJ/eU9cD0PIrNVot2NJYWolcjVQOtPRc/epAVJGSMHpU0QywIPIPB9KpsySaG7emaz9TVTPEWBwYyv61qOcscnJPeqGolfOgULuYAnBqbmiWoaddw2sJSd2G4gqFQnI71sxyJJCrxMGRuVYd6564hYLA8kcimJixKnJI7jFaejybtPQ4YfM2AeuM1LKZ1uj3xuYzC7fvYhwT3WtVHK9a5G1u47Odbma5W3ROTgbmcegXvWhD4s025DG2E8hxnBTB9uO341hOyZ007tEHjbVXS2ihgJIRhK+D1I6CsW3aHXtMU7hLaucFQOc/3SaZq1559wfMfO8cZ6fSuLu7+fw5qcs1m/kx3BDYP3A49fTIqFHmZ0RlyGxL4ZurW8dbDw5atGzYDuWK/XGa1GtJ9K08LdrCJZOFRBgL+Arnbr4qaiYggg2P1LA1gXXia/1e5DTzMA3Bw2TinyS6mjqpnS31xEWFtbSBpXI8x852j396r67Jb2+maQ11am5t0vC0kIfb5gC9M1HFZqNNMq9c5OKreK7pYtH09F+8s5dh/wABxRFe8iZSbiz1vQPGWkaxFBFayLbT7QotHIDDA6DsfwroDPg8An1r5/0ZoL1wp2MVO9Q1d9Z6jqlnbK9lqBWDhWju4/P8k9ufvbfTk4rreEk1eDueYsbGLcamh6FLMM4z0qu75U1gaNrd5dl0vmhllUMx8lCoIXr1PNa9hdw39uZISSucYIwRXPUhKDtI6KdWNRXiUJpQmvJGTwyBcVdcEmsLXJHh1ouvVNuPqK6IDeiuBw3NSzREKj1p+0UrLtBPpUfmL60XA8iBzz1PpTGiyaeOKeK6UZORD9lVh1+b0qo9kWQkgZB/OtMY645oAGOlUjKTOee0lSQMI2HrxUMsZH3lIbtmurGGHNQy2kU/31Jx+FUjFs563vZ4CCJG47dq1YPEMZADxEHHJHrSy6GpmDRNtTHRqqXOiTRKGT94D/d7VQcxvW13DcqGhcN6gdRVkKsh2S8oevGePpXG7J7YYwUYHIYDB/OtKy12SE4uFLg8bu4oMmne6Nm28KSahqqnQrw6fcMCSzn5OPX61a0jwj4k8QSiXXLiXR4YnIkuC/zS9gFTOB354HPSktL8TJutbjy2YY35xisPXNWvLOdre11ppUPUxxFPwrnqqSdkenhpRlC8nqd1pfhWzn1b7Na61qE0Nlb+W7sV2wlj9wDHJOMk1yHi3w7qXhfUrK/luo7mxllYRTxqVKH0ZegyPwPNP8N/ECPRNKksbiFnDvukkC7ncY6DPT611Og/EzSJrN7K+gEMUMLsZHO4MxHK49STxWXK07nRdSjuc7pni77APss8aPGhyrFA2VPbPtV+78TR7jNB5LwkAkIMEfWvPxMUZmYHAHGeoohu/vZO0k49j+FO1tjBtSVmekWmsWN4rYkMci9UcZ/EY6ioHuoYbz7bcQXFzb5CIkPQn3PUfSuLNyVjV7dyJkxhgOnt7itLTNRlvSyCUpLjn0P1oc7oz9mou50upX9kRFdRyzQwRsS8bxksBjnjvVVfHOmg2tnZRSx2zMVa7kYeaf8AgI6DnpVSZruCIm0lJVifOtpFDA/TPv2rIn0+21ZhPDH5N8ONij5JgOv+647DofrRzaagoJvQ7Jrq/sZS728VzaN964jz5ig9yPbPaqram9jrS/2gI5YbpB5Vyg/IZ7jHaquja+93YRwwsn2yEBMuOT2Ab6jjPY1YktYNX0ieBQyKwJQE8wSjqB6Zx0rF6HQkmWfEc1vaWHnyyKsOzBPzZ3Z+UE4OAfX8K5G7MGp2pRjndnZuI2se2GHB/n7VqaDqjXsclnqDbpYT5ZJ7jtWhceFdNuIWW3H2V9hKyxdiORuXow9jQnbQdjym5jnsbh4XOGU9KvaYYb5/JKbLvrEy8ByP4SPU9j64qxqts1jeNa6xC6vHwk0XzK4PQjPUfjVVbSyZgIb+NHz8pKsBntkkcfnWykTY7SynS50XC5DqMMvrWH4mUzwsqjPkqpYCklvZ7KaO6nD4kyJkQZCyDr/30MN+Jq3YQXHiFZoLGJ0e4b99PMNqRp3x3J9AKShroDn7t2c3YyRo6q8jRMOjDoa67SdXv7GUSEi6gIw65yCvcGt3xFoJt/Bs1npNnG5Owu8sYDuqjqg7H9eteW2+oXVo+Y5XGOMGuuM3T3OCVNV03E9k0u6MN7E8BLwSSqE+YNgNjIOPStPwtKtxqYKghPnHA69etef+CPEEk1zfz3mEisbZrwsB94rgKp+rEV1nwylla+WORs5ieUg9s44/WssVNTaki8JTdFOMjX12Pdqk4xnB4rd0k+dpkXcrlTWLqXmSXU5PJyWJFXfDkrrLJC3RlDqCK53sdKeppXuILKaRuMIcfWuZ/tBvVq6XXWEelykkDPAyM8muO8xv7w/IU0hs4oOPXnvT1cHoc1UjOY1O4NnuBUq/KPWulbHJJ2di0oGOT+lPAHY5FV8gYIGKd5jkYUj6Ggl6loJgZzSqBgqD3zUCysO+R6VIJgRyM/jVIzaJsZApQOMZA+hpqyqBwuKjLlz6YqkQyQwhuHAYfSqs+j20wO0FGP8AdNWkJPBdV9s04llACEbc5zTJuYcunXWm4mjmU7ehAxV61ubu5DQzxlHI4YAA49qviRm4PI+lTKoUccCk1cuFRx1OL1SWGwYxNbM03XeTkGss3b3DlTiOMjhdwAz6n1rs9e0oahbFk++ntXBXNs9vIQwPBrKWh3UpqaNFrhEfyySWb5QVOR7fWrb2wMZV1x0INZFvIUKgMoJGMnqMVtyTb7ZCdu7ZyR39qxk7GqiVJWaEdNy0QyvG7SRuyl+uPSo7e5MkzNJErquAVkJx9TjmqkszQuhGM47VN7lJaHSQ6g8ocO+HjwVP94U2LVDJKbhMeYjDeAMBvfFZSSKRwcHaDnPSo7aYDVSjNtSQbWP170hctmdC04sPEqXi4C3SfOp4BycPn9GGO5ralvjpuuxOrZg1GI59PMXgn8sZ9641rpriyYNIB5IcjJ747fkK1bi4N3pkRDgvbXCyJj+669fzFJjH6uBpeux3MTZjmIziuus9U3WwK7Vb1PPauN1djdTRuxGBg4AxViwnIxGykkDnBpblbHQ3kUGpFkmjSXzOPn7fQdhXA6v4bksZ3+ynemfuHqPp612a6isZGQVIOcHk0lzPZ3cRMrYLDK7RkimroTZw+latPZT7GmlAceX1wV+ma6ux1PyXBt9Z8rcNy/abMEH/AIEh/pWBq+msC42jzUOeO49RWt4S1log1k+m298s75WCSMN+9A5255+YY49Qa2pyszmrK8bo7Ox1vxBMgjjbQtQUj7q3AUkfRgDXnHiTTb658VTW50VbG6lwy20JyvT7+c4APUnOBXXvJogkkbVPDsumJGhd5lkeML6bVP3iTwAK4jWPEb3oe00yD7Dp7HlAd0k/oZXPLfT7o7Ctqmxlhk7t9PmWvMh0/TX0yzmWYysHu7lDlZGX7qJ6opJOf4jz0Art/Al4NMvYLmYgo+YmGMEZ6Y/KvK4w8cg3ElSMiu68PRvcC1nU/ubefc5JP904H61y1XbQ7acbtnol+/mzyOp2A9icHHpT9DnaPU054PynPNPvfs9wsc6qAWjUtj1pNHj8rWYxjg54/Cl0JsXvFMyLbx24J3FtxGOgrmNldD4qj2zwyZJ3J68DBrnt9CEeb2mUjOST6ZFW1eo2Vl+8KFOeldS2OWfxFkPnqDSg5OagGcZyacrEdKZBaRgeMD60p61AkhB5qYOrDk0hD1YjmhXLZpmFHzLlvUd6kDegAzVJkNC7sc59sYqTzcAA8+nFRdKUH5xiqRiyyPnQruxg8e9TkhYAe/pVcOfmwMA8E4p4lygTjjv3pkXLCMCAGzx6VQ1LQ7TUssoWOTHXHWrMbhmPNTIAT1x9aUoqS1Lp1JRd0cTqPhS5Rl+zRGQD+7zWdJZajp7o1zC8a5zhv8K9N3kYxx9Kjv7aO6tRHMAy5A59K5nSa6noRxd7XR5fJecusan5j1NV5W3uPpXa6p4EmAE+nKsqn+AnDCseXwTrWXk+ybUHTLjJ+lQvQ6eePcw3mK4C9e9TQyAX6M4+6Bn8qsTeHNWgiEsljKI+u4YP54qkhPnvIf4eTQxpp7FuZxi72jIMjf5/WtfS5vNt0ibAV4dv4q3Fc6JP9GIzy2c/nWzpTfu4QeAAefSkwLt5EC/mLkMcAAfTvUVndMLnITD7Tk+oqWUnz3ZmG0jH09Kz5LpbW4SZl3hRyo6/nUobNhrl5I9qMjuRnbg5/OqDNI6M5+VwcEjimtrcO6KSJjEwJGCp4H1qcT/ZIleaIFZFDK5HBqkS0VPtkpwjsNoOVz1FVw7Wt6xjbBLBlb0wcj8qdIULEsQCfbpUN5tWFdpO9RyexHtVIzfY0/EWs32vWELXdxNMIpCGaRs4YjgfofzNYSxTBQMrgdM1fiRLiGbcVRSnmAn19PxOaqrNJF/AGWuhK+rIXurlRXd5EcB69N8DWTXugyfOVLSsBjtwMH9K86uws0SyIPmB5X2rs/COpNZwWsaLPl+6EbR65rmxETooS6npL4EIXoQBTrCcLqEDEBcHk+tVWkZid2OmeKrG4eB1YgFgcgGhR0M5T1Or8RWyXFgJzwYzwc9Qetct5cPrVu81+5urQowi2swyAnT6Vm/aj/dFCiLmPPvvDuaQcdKGBUkUgORW0JaGdSOpKDkYNKOvtUa80u7B61VzJolJAFOVhjpmq5fNORiKpMhxLKPz6VOpBXnvVRZCe/SrCOH64BpNkNDgvOB+frUqrt+9SJBvcASAAnqeBUsVsDEXaYKCTsDAjfj0Pek6kYvUFSlJXig3cYHSnofXpTfJYHqfpTwO3f24q7mTj3QoK7sjdn9KlZ1jQu7hQBkkmkWI4Gen1ohydQsW8gTBJwzRs2AwHr9OvviiUrK4Qp88kh0V9bSyiNLiMuMfKWAq0AJRipvEn2rVNMe4FrZWs0cge1MT7pJ1JxjGBgY559KzdGvWu4v3mN6naSOma541XLc7a2GVNXia0M2Ymy2TnHSk5PXkenYUyJP9Yo7NmnAY5JP0FadTlZWggtrZ4xPJKhnfao3kAn6VxHjDwzLpl5JLbRn7I/zLgdD3Fdnqw/d2soB/dSqevvWtqVpHe2E0cvOAWX61E0b0Z8rPEkhc44rWs8xhF6Enk1MYFm1aZI0GxMk/TFMxtl46DpWTO6+po/LPBh+SPSsq7jACccYq9HJhSD3qKRBImSOnrSKM+zEbS+TIuVY1d/spgAI53WMnIU/MBVFx5MquOMGtpJDNZ5j+9jnNJsaA+Grd4lKy5Pq54zVC9t4zbNEDiSE4x7U+DUpLeXa/zxn+FulVpptx39M8cdxVRTM5tDdGm2zpGcbZA0L5HZv/AK9IqGN2GNwU7SPSq9uxhuCB3II/A5FWLmVYdTlZvuljuHrmumnKxhNXloLLGhhZsfMBWr4UuWGrtatyiJtGPXgf41mvteAMucEjHvV3wuDDes4HzFsc/WoxBVFtJnrBZfvg9KqXIDL0Jz6VHBOZJfKJ2+tW3TA7celSkRJ6kSZNiQcYDcDFQ8VsWWlTXtnOI2j3YDhcnNQ/8I7ff3aLhZvU8wcEc5zmoxkfSiOR3UYOfYjpSvlerwj/AHiQahSsdLhcXJ9MinAE8bSKjLxDALM2eTscUJLZlmBMzY6c1XOR7Mk2kHJ/nSb1DYLAfjQs9ipyYLh+Om4AURSIXyV8mM/dUdfzpqRDgPSQA+v0UmpxINwCo7E/7NMQqwxluvrVgKhGVwCPfk1VzFxJrSFrudIjMtuDzukG4YHUYHU4zWpcwQvpE4uro3TIpa3HlGMR9+h6fQVyGqa3JayiK1KKg+845Le30+lPt9exJF83lwqSRETnyz6nPUVlON3c66D5YWZo6frVokUhuXfJkIQKpYnHYCtxPIlVZFwNwGAev5V54khg1GS6QOFd2KH+IA/1rWsdYfzAkMxQr/eOcfnVp2RjUpKTuda7xxvtD7j3AU8VS1G5ihiM8pKFOVION3tj+tUU1mNA/wBoctg/Mw4ANV/EDGWwgeAMzSMFBcggg1bd0ZwpWkmW2u5NRt1MaLDbPbHaoYkgHIwxPfvVzQIIX1B47WX5VQlmVCwwvbP9az5rqabSorErChGA8saYYqOgHb1q9HNNY6WtvaM4hdcOsZAyfVj3qIw7nXWnZWsdFEInd/KfIP58VHMhTkng9PeuU0y+m8w+aHEYYqjnP15rfa7haMNPKBnAULklj6AVo0ee0mTajA82mmOJN0jEFfzFayAvasWXJKms2FxuAG4Af3hitITRQWE0s2SioSTnqKl7Cjuefmx+ypeXsuFM37uFO5GeW/wrOeDbGrHuetWJ75tRuyD/AKpSdoHYVNOg+zke1YyVj0Iu5mkgADuOtRs5HQGlmODVWVyD8uQaSLEucNEQBz61NplyBAyt1xVfdlagV/LlO3gHrRYLk90u1x7VDncuKlnbKhvWoEPBFaRRjNkUmVkHPPrV7U4N95uXBSWNZFI6cj/Gs+Vst9K1lkNxZIm3Jh5Uj+6ex/H+dawWpE3azKNjKQxhk5wSwrV0ST94hBG7zAee/NZdzEEljkTKjODVzQbiK2vFe4YBFyeR37VFRFxd9UegmTfI0ydCxHHAq+LrZa72DYHLHHArK06dbzT98cbqC2ACME++Kq6jdTxQvbhgIz1GOfxohdozqWTZe07xbNZX1zJBCrbwAgbIx9SD+lX/APhPdW/552/5H/GuISVvNAzxnnnFWd8fr/49VcqM1UdjBEc24+WQQP7wNI6lhulUBh3Unn86fMziVFU5C89aHB2Z6kjtXMtT0myEyvHEoVCQxPGRmovtJU7dkgPcA1Ngm3+VF3Z4JPNdT9jEWiW8tou2RF3ykKME/XrQ3YEuY5VJJT/y7sT6PJgD8KvQyF1UArvByQOg9qgkP2mQuH3EcsVOcmpvtBaNVkdTIO4AziqRlNFtC6t82AT78VUv9QVYjHGd3PzOOPyqG9u1CfK2dvUmqUFpNeSJ5gMcWc5I5NVcjkW7Ksj+bPyTjOBmruwHLkgACotWVUukCAKFHaoYbhjwcH2an0NIWLMj5gII2kkc1peHbHSpbuSXWZ5lRDsjggO12OMlt3QAdMd8+1Y0s/2iRQwxt6ADg1BKds7EHknNJa6FS01OivtFa6v2GmuBZ5+R5Gzj2x1JFWbuPy4orCElzCnyyMeS+cms/wAOXUhkliVNyKm8sf4K1NMRW1UX10AltAxCqx46ck/nWi0OWd73JLWKafaxTC4+Y56H6d6tWDqXZSFVWJIJbOSOOKz7O8juTdpaSbEEvysR95amWXEnzzPIVxgtgAew9Kq5tVjzU7nQ2thCYpXmjU228OoY8EjufTkVj63qqXN0qRbQ0bhtynI/CtvW4dmm2ltbzxzrNGrP8wXyxwSOP61DFbWYzmzgdm6OUBI/GhO6OKcXB6k93PsgmePPzL2IHb3qxpjfadCmhlYMyxt0cN274rP1P/jykGAxPQbc4+gpfDzm2gn83KRuhwCvLds1LJirq5zWnqjRNhSSOSBwcU+4feMJ29aooxinYA5IJBq4848l8ouWGMkZxWdRWOug7oozr3zVKQ4HTg9DVppD0HNV3AJzUI1ZVY7VJqCc4HBqe4+7j1qm64GKtIm5bjffB9ajVtrkVHBJtyvY06Zi23pwMcDFaWIa1GOcv+NaOnt/pMaM5VJfkYj3HH61mk9KuQkgIR1A/lVw3IqLQtNFucq3fqPQiqVlK8Uu+MKWAP3jxVxrgNPlujdT71U0oF75VMe/r8nrxRVsKlezub+l6/dR3MSySJGNww8Wdy/Q102p22nzgy2d1Pcu43NJMm3B5yMfhXHQiSe6UQxvAewZQAK6i0h36dMk853oC6hfutxzWcWKbMORWRwecelJ5x9KeS8mCc7QOBngUmytLmdjMl+9SCiiuVHoPciX7rfWunP/ACKMv/XM/wA6KKUtkXDqcvpf+rb6Gkb/AI/5voP5UUVXQSK6/wDHzD/v1vt/rfwFFFDMpbGHq3/H1SWvQfWiiq6F0txYf+PmSqkv+uNFFCLqGpon3Zvwrfl/5Azf7slFFHU5pGJ4e/1z/wC8P5VtT/8AHlJ/u0UVoa/YLeh/f/4D/U1tQ/dT6UUVRxyNPTf+PpPqKf4y/wCQyv8A17Ciis5blQ+E8yj/AOPqT61Zb/j1NFFKp0Lomev+sH1qDtRRULc0kV5vv1Xk60UVqjNEaf6ypn+6KKKoct0Rd6uwdV+lFFOIpjJfux/WrOif8hhf94/yoopT2FHYu2P/ACEZvr/Wug0//j1k/wCuJooqY7kS2M+P7p+lFFFWSf/Z" /></p>
<p>
    Text right after the image.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

the following code works for me:

```
DECLARE
    conn utl_smtp.connection;
    BOUNDARY  VARCHAR2 (256) := '-----090303020209010600070908';
    i         pls_integer;
    len       pls_integer;
    buff_size pls_integer := 57;
    l_raw     raw(57);
    p_image blob;
    MailServer          VARCHAR2(50) := 'xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx';
     l_message            VARCHAR2(32767) :='<html>
<body>
<img src="cid:banner" alt="banner"/>
<br>
Test HTML with Embedded Image-chk latest
<p>And here it is:</p>
<p>The end.</p>
</body>
</html>
';
begin
SELECT PIC
INTO p_image
FROM TEMP_MAIL_PIC_BLOB
WHERE PIC_ID = 1;
conn := utl_smtp.open_connection(MailServer, 25);
UTL_SMTP.helo (conn, MailServer);
UTL_SMTP.mail (conn, 'from@abc.com');
UTL_SMTP.rcpt (conn, 'to@abc.com');
UTL_SMTP.open_data (conn);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (conn, 'From' || ': ' || 'from@test.com'|| UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (conn, 'To' || ': ' || 'to@test.com'|| UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (conn, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (conn, 'Subject: image inline testing' || UTL_TCP.CRLF) ;
UTL_SMTP.write_data (conn, 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' || BOUNDARY || '"' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (conn, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (conn,  '--' || BOUNDARY || UTL_TCP.CRLF );
UTL_SMTP.write_data (conn,  'Content-Type: text/html; charset=US-ASCII'|| UTL_TCP.CRLF );
UTL_SMTP.write_data (conn, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (conn, l_message);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (conn, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (conn,  '--' || BOUNDARY || UTL_TCP.CRLF );
UTL_SMTP.write_data (conn,  'Content-Type: image/jpg;'|| UTL_TCP.CRLF );
UTL_SMTP.write_data (conn, 'Content-Disposition: inline; filename="banner.jpg"' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA (conn, 'Content-ID: <banner> ' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);   
UTL_SMTP.write_data (conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding' || ': ' || 'base64' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (conn, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
i := 1;
len := dbms_lob.getlength(p_image);
while i < len
loop
  dbms_lob.read(p_image, buff_size, i, l_raw);
  utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn, utl_encode.base64_encode(l_raw));
  utl_smtp.write_data(conn, utl_tcp.crlf);
  i := i + buff_size;
end loop;
utl_smtp.write_data(conn, utl_tcp.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data (conn, '--' || BOUNDARY || '--' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (conn, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.close_data (conn);
UTL_SMTP.quit (conn);
end;
```

Regards
Giova

Comment: Thanks for the response Giova.  It now works for a single or multiple embedded image(s).  A new problem came to light.  When tested on a Hotmail account in Office/Outlook 2013, the image shows up properly inside the body.  However, when viewing the same eMail by logging into Hotmail through a browser, the same image shows up as a attachments with thumbnails.  The body of the eMail shows the ALT text instead of the image.  We need to send eMails to a public audience who may be suspicious of attachments.  Would links to images on a server avoid this problem?  Any other ideas?  Thanks. Phil

Comment: Maybe you need to have it accessible on a webserver.
you are just sending a webpage, an html page. It can have URLs in it, the url is resolved on the 
client. unless that client has logowin.gif on c:\ -- it'll never find it.
So, put logowin.gif on a webserver and use 
http://thatserver/img/logwin.gif

Comment: You can try also the following:
<https://community.oracle.com/message/9678442#9678442> You have to send an html with image code embedded in it.